# How could I run created artisan commands from a route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to run a command what I´v created in a route like this:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
     Artisan::call('ponto:sync');
     return "running command";
});
```

and also I tried that:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
     Artisan::call('generate:form');
     return "running command";
});
```

but i'm getting this error: "Class asset.publisher does not exist"
I want to know if is possible to do something like that?
and how do I fix that?

thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a problem in another thing: `asset.publisher`. Search for it in your source code. Seems like a error related to a ServiceProvider, but you're giving use too few information to work with. Is you application working?

Comment: Yes my command is working, when I use the in Linux shell works fine, I also had tried to run other commands like db:seed and migrate but didnt work too, is right to call a command like "Artisan::call(command)"??  thx!

Comment: Yeah, it't the correct way. I just tested it here and it works: http://puu.sh/6BA5w.png.

Comment: I was searching how fix that the problem, is that asset publisher u are right. I'll try to fix that but at the moment I just found the same issue with laravel debug bar, thank u

Comment: hahaha a composer update and dump--autoload fixed that issue, thx for help Antonio